# Maven JAXB plugin and locale for generated output

Tags: maven, jaxb, locale, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` (from `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2`) to generate classes from an XSD schema.  All is working fine and the generated classes are all that I need.  Except for one thing, all the generated comments inside those classes are using my computer locale (which is french).

I'd like to be able to change the locale of the generated comments (to use english for example).  Can it be done through the plugin configuration or the project configuration in the `pom.xml` ?  Or must it be done in my shell when I run the `mvn` command?

I tried setting the `project.build.sourceEncoding` but that doesn't change the locale.  I tried setting the `user.language` or `user.country` but that doesn't have any effect on the output.

There is an option to pass some arguments to the `xjc` command that I could use, but I cannot find anything related to locale when calling `xjc`.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to put the following into your pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

The above will also influence the maven-compiler-plugin etc. Furthermore the jaxb2-maven-plugin will also be influenced by the above property (${project.build.sourceEncoding}).

Comment: I already have that and it doesn't change anything to the locale used in the output.  It sets the charset correctly, but not the locale.  I tried using `en_GB.UTF-8` as a sourceEncoding, but that is not supported by maven.  That just doesn't seem to be the way to do it.